# Mixed Content and SSL Sites / Protocol Relative URLs

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, https

I have a site that was all HTTP until recently, when it was requested that we add an SSL cert because there was a concern about MIM attacks with a login applet on the home page.  I bought the cert, but realized that there are a lot of protocol specific links in the HTML.  I know using protocol relative links is one suggested technique, but that means every one of my sites which I link to for a JS include or image will need a cert as well, right?  I assume a wildcard cert might be useful if every include was from the same domain, but I have multiple domains, and the includes span across several of them, so I can't just have CN=*.mydomain.com

How do I handle this?  RHEL 6, Apache 2.2.15 (RHEL backported version), SNI is enabled, mod_ssl, etc.

Comment: It would be a complete hack, but check out mod_proxy_html for apache

Comment: There's also a type of SSL certificate where you can specify a number of secondary domains. The SSL certificate vendors tend to charge per-5 domains or so, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All content needs to be served through HTTPS to avoid warnings.  What good would SSL do if an attacker could still do a MITM attack and alter say, the jquery js you are loading?  They could still change everything through javascript.

So your options are:

- Move/copy everything to the same domain.  By moving the files, or reverse proxy, or other tricks.
- Get seperate SSL certs for each domain (which also often means seperate IP addresses if they are on the same server)
- Get a SAN (Subject Alternate Name) certificate.  This allows you to have one cert that covers several specified domains and/or subdomains.  How many domains depends on the provider and how much you pay.  They can often be combined with wildcards to cover all subdomains.

Comment: Can you discuss some of the Search Engine implications that having an HTTP and an HTTPS version of a site have, and what the best practices in this regard are please?

Comment: @usedtobeamember that would probably be better answered in a new question.  Possibly on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com